# I am getting an error using geom_density_2d in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and new to programming. I'm currently trying to use geom_density_2d in ggplot to graph a simple heat map using the faithful dataset. Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
library(tidyverse)

m <- faithful %>%  ggplot(aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) +
geom_point() +
xlim(0.5, 6) +
ylim(40, 110)
m + geom_density_2d() 

m + geom_density_2d(aes(fill = stat(level)), geom = "polygon")
```

The first graph works just fine, but when I try to run the second I get the following error message:

'Error in stat(level) : could not find function "stat"'

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Running your code, i do not get the error under r-3.4.4. By the way, you copied this from the documentation: do you mean `m + stat_density_2d(aes(fill = stat(level)), geom = "polygon") `?

Comment: Some related discussion here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/options-to-stat-density-2d/792/4

Comment: I believe you need ggplot2 version 3 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same error using the example for stat https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat.html

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(count)))
```

However, as some of my packages were out of date I was able to resolve it by 1) restarting R and 2) running:

```
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)
```